# Class not found error using namespaces and "use"

Tags: php, class, import, namespaces

I'm new to PHP and I'm following an online course (for this reason I'm not using autoloading or any other way to load classes).

My problem is that my controller class (in which I'm using "use") cannot see my model class (in which I've declared the namespace).

The error is:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'App\Models\Post' not found in C:\xampp_php729\htdocs\Freeblog\App\Controllers\postController.php on line 20

Here is my code:

PostController.php

```
namespace App\Controllers;

use App\Models\Post;

class PostController {

    protected $layout = __DIR__ . '/../../Layout/index.template.php';
    protected $conn;
    public $content;
    public $posts;
    protected $myPost;

    public function __construct(\PDO $conn) {
        $this->conn = $conn;

        try {

            $this->myPost = new Post($conn);
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            die($e->getMessage());
        }
        $this->content = $this->process();
    }
....
}
```

Post.php:

```
namespace App\Models;
use \PDO;


class Post {

    protected $conn;

    public function __construct(PDO $conn){
        $this->conn = $conn;

    } 
...
}
```

This is the project structure:

[image: Project structure]

Comment: So how do you expect to file to be included (__loaded__) if you don't use any __autoloading__?

Comment: I don't know I'm attending a course to learn it :)

Comment: In other two php files I've done the same thing and it worked.. the only difference is that they are in the same package (but I've tried to move Post and PostController in the same package and it doesn't work)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are not using autoloading, files in directory other than Controllers will not load.

So if you do not want to use autoloading, you should either use include statement or require statement to include the files manually(files which are in other directory).(Include file Post.php in PostController.php file)

As mentioned in your comments, other files which are working must be getting loaded because they exist in the same directory(same package does not matters here but same directory matters for other files to get loaded).

Comment: Thanks so much! I was missing the "require" part in my index.php. Unfortunately I was focusing on this two files, not looking in the others :(